# Solve $(dy/dx)^2 = c+x^2y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(dy/dx)^2 = c+x^2y^2.$$
How can I solve it?

I'm doing the problem
$$DyD^2y - x^2yDy -xy^2 =0,$$
I have already reached the above condition and am not able to solve any further.

Comment: @Dan RHS has degree $2+2n$ not $2+n$, so no nontrivial polynomial solutions.

Comment: Are there perhaps initial conditions that force $c=0$?

Comment: Maple does not solve this in closed form.

Comment: @user10354138: Oops, my bad: I missed one of the 2's.  Anyhow, the $original$ equation $y'y'' x^2yy' - xy^2$ would be a degree $2n + 1$ polynomial.

Comment: @Dan But unfortunately, if you look for a polynomial solution then by matching the coefficients of $x^{2n+1}$ you get an infeasible result, so still no polynomial solutions to be had.